# How to create a server which hosts both PHP and Django sites on different domains

Tags: django, wordpress, apache, nginx, server

I am on ubuntu 16.04 server and seeking to deploy 3 domains on the ip.
1 is WordPress site rest 2 are Django site.

But I can find a proper way of doing it.

Should I create different docker containers?
Or use Nginx blocks?
Or should I deploy a LAMP server with virtual host and use nginx as reverse proxy?

I have no issues with serving sites from different ports.

Comment: Have your applications running in different ports, using reverse proxy render your applications.

Comment: Nothing has been deployed yet, I did an installation with docker but deleted that.